# Python unit test when structure changes

Tags: python, unit-testing

Using the below sample data:

```
 { "query":{
          "pages":{
             "25618423":{
                "pageid":25618423,
                "ns":0,
                "title":"1983 Wimbledon Championships - Women's Singles"
             },
             "23826062":{
                "pageid":23826062,
                "ns":0,
                "title":"1984 French Open - Women's Singles"
             },
             "29486043":{
                "pageid":29486043,
                "ns":0,
                "title":"1984 Wimbledon Championships - Women's Doubles"
             },
             "25618558":{
                "pageid":25618558,
                "ns":0,
                "title":"1984 Wimbledon Championships - Women's Singles"
             }}}
```

I extract each object:

```
{ "pageid":25618423, "ns":0, "title":"1983 Wimbledon Championships - Women's Singles"}
```

and add to an array. It seems works but I want to unit test to make sure.

So I created a finished array for testing. Against this I test raw data processed through my function. However while the content of the data doesn't change the order of each element changes. And so when I use assertEqual it fails.

Is this a bad way to unit test? Am I using the wrong assertion?

Thanks

Comment: Dictionaries are orderless. The order that's assigned to them as a `__repr__` shouldn't matter to anything. Without seeing your unittest code, it's impossible to know where the mistake is, but if you're doing everything properly it's NOT an unstable sorting error.

Comment: You could also do a sort of the list before you compare. `mySortedArray = sorted(myArray, key=lambda page: page['pageid'])` This sorts your list based on the pageid